# Why am I seeing a Tomcat issue in my Java 8 App's App Engine Standard Edition logs? org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory location

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tomcat

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor: 
The XML schema [XMLSchema.dtd] could not be found. 
This is very likely to break XML validation 
if XML validation is enabled. (DigesterFactory.java:154)
```

I thought Jetty was the underlying container used by App Engine. And I haven't made any known changes on my app code.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a Java web container with the potential for log issues and a variety of options. Jetty is used by Google App Engine. It's possible to utilize it with Tomcat if you use Flexible VM, but it is not recommended.

App Engine isn't a set of web servers; rather, it is a collection of services that assist you in creating a scalable app.

Here is the [The Java 8 / Jetty 9 Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9) documentation that could help you.